# LEFT JOIN subquery fails in the presence of an EXISTS clause in the main query

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery, mariadb-10.3

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT c.id contact_id, engagement.sent
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN (
    /* ➊ Inner query */
    SELECT eq.contact_id contact_id, COUNT(*) sent
    FROM mailing_job j
    INNER JOIN mailing_event_queue eq ON eq.job_id = j.id
    WHERE j.end_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
    GROUP BY eq.contact_id
  ) engagement ON engagement.contact_id = c.id

 WHERE
  /* ➋ various conditions on table 'c' */
 do_not_email = 0 AND is_opt_out = 0 AND is_deceased = 0 AND is_deleted = 0
   AND contact_type = 'Individual'

   /* ➌ */
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT gc.contact_id
      FROM group_contact gc
      WHERE gc.contact_id = c.id AND gc.group_id IN (30,386,14,6,214,5,88,361,334,18,9,17,240,7,13,10,292,291,290,12)
    )

   /* ➍ AND c.id=1 */
ORDER BY c.id
```

- The inner query ➊ when run on its own yields results, e.g. *sent: 15*  for contact *1*. This is the correct, expected data.
- However, running the whole query gives *NULL* for the whole *sent* column! Which is vexing me.
- Eliminating the WHERE clauses at ➋, *or* eliminating the EXISTS at ➌, *or including* the commented out ➍ clause causes it to behave and return *sent: 15* for the test contact.

I'm on MariaDB 10.3.

### EDIT

Hoping to add clarity. Fundamentally this is weird -I think- and possibly a bug in MariaDB, though I hope not!

The Inner query ➊ returns rows, e.g.

```
contact_id  sent
1           15
...
```

The main query also picks up contact with ID `1`.

Now in all my years, when I've left joined a table on a primary key (i.e. `c.id`) where a record in the subquery matches, it's never changed its values.

The fact that those values come and go with changing other WHERE clauses, but in ways that still mean the outer query generates the matching contact ID, I think, is weird.

I'm really hoping I've done something stupid, but I can't see it.

Comment: If none rows returned then none row matches **all** conditions. This is not "query fails".

Comment: Do you mean that adding the `AND c.id=1` condition changes the result of the query from one row (with id=1 sent=15) to one row (with id=1, sent=NULL)?

Comment: if you produce a [mre] we could help you

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ yes that's what I mean.

Comment: @nbk quite. But I cannot reproduce this in that way (I have tried). The database it's running on has between 200k and 10M rows in each table.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I suggest you file a bug report to MariaDB.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ done https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-25168

Comment: they will ask you to reprocude zthe error, as you can#t nobpdy can fix it

Comment: What is `eq`???

Comment: @RickJames `eq` is a table alias, defined at: `INNER JOIN mailing_event_queue eq`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug. Please send a bug report to MariaDB. Some details:

First, make sure it is a bug.

Query A produces a single row (assuming that `contact (id)` has a unique (or primary key) constraint:

```
-- Query A 
SELECT c.id contact_id
FROM contact c

 WHERE
  /* ➋ various conditions on table 'c' */
 c.do_not_email = 0 AND c.is_opt_out = 0 AND c.is_deceased = 0 AND c.is_deleted = 0
   AND c.contact_type = 'Individual'

   /* ➌ */
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT gc.contact_id
      FROM group_contact gc
      WHERE gc.contact_id = c.id AND gc.group_id IN (30,386,14,6,214,5,88,361,334,18,9,17,240,7,13,10,292,291,290,12)
    )

   /* ➍ */
   AND c.id=1
ORDER BY c.id ;
```

Query B produces one row (with value `15` in `sent`)

```
-- Query B
/* ➊ Inner query */
SELECT eq.contact_id contact_id, COUNT(*) sent
FROM mailing_job j
INNER JOIN mailing_event_queue eq ON eq.job_id = j.id
WHERE j.end_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
  AND eq.contact_id = 1
GROUP BY eq.contact_id ;
```

Query C produces a single row but with value `NULL` (or anything different than the `15` in Query B).

```
-- Query C 
SELECT c.id contact_id, engagement.sent
FROM contact c
LEFT JOIN (
    /* ➊ Inner query */
    SELECT eq.contact_id contact_id, COUNT(*) sent
    FROM mailing_job j
    INNER JOIN mailing_event_queue eq ON eq.job_id = j.id
    WHERE j.end_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
    GROUP BY eq.contact_id
  ) engagement ON engagement.contact_id = c.id
    
 WHERE
  /* ➋ various conditions on table 'c' */
 c.do_not_email = 0 AND c.is_opt_out = 0 AND c.is_deceased = 0 AND c.is_deleted = 0
   AND c.contact_type = 'Individual'

   /* ➌ */
   AND EXISTS (
      SELECT gc.contact_id
      FROM group_contact gc
      WHERE gc.contact_id = c.id AND gc.group_id IN (30,386,14,6,214,5,88,361,334,18,9,17,240,7,13,10,292,291,290,12)
    )

   /* ➍ */
   AND c.id=1
ORDER BY c.id ;
```

If the above do happen, it's almost surely either a bug or corrupted data in tables/indexes.

Other things to check / add to the report:

- Execution plans for all queries (use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`)
- Complete `CREATE TABLE` for all tables involved, including indexes. You can use `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename ;` for that.
- Your exact version of MariadDB (try `select version();` ).
- Try dropping and recreating the indexes on the tables involved if possible (not the tables!) and then test again.
- If you are not running the latest 10.3, try upgrading to the latest 10.3 if possible, and test again.
- If you have available servers with more recent major versions (10.4 or 10.5), try recreating the tables with the same data and test again.
- Try to remove conditions (as you did) or rewrite C and test if it produces different plan and correct or wrong results, eg.:

  - remove each one of these:

    ```
      do_not_email = 0 AND is_opt_out = 0 AND is_deceased = 0 AND is_deleted = 0
      AND contact_type = 'Individual'
    ```
  - remove the `ORDER BY`
  - remove subqueries 3 and/or 4.
  - add a condition in b subquery:

    ```
      LEFT JOIN (
          /* ➊ Inner query */
          SELECT eq.contact_id contact_id, COUNT(*) sent
          FROM mailing_job j
          INNER JOIN mailing_event_queue eq ON eq.job_id = j.id
          WHERE j.end_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
            AND eq.contact_id = 1
          GROUP BY eq.contact_id
        ) engagement ON engagement.contact_id = c.id
    ```
  - rewrite the whole query as:

    ```
      -- Query Z
      SELECT z.contact_id, engagement.sent
      FROM
          (
          SELECT c.id contact_id
          FROM contact c

           WHERE
            /* ➋ various conditions on table 'c' */
           c.do_not_email = 0 AND c.is_opt_out = 0 AND c.is_deceased = 0 AND c.is_deleted = 0
             AND c.contact_type = 'Individual'

             /* ➌ */
             AND EXISTS (
                SELECT gc.contact_id
                FROM group_contact gc
                WHERE gc.contact_id = c.id AND gc.group_id IN (30,386,14,6,214,5,88,361,334,18,9,17,240,7,13,10,292,291,290,12)
              )

             /* ➍ */
             AND c.id=1
          ) AS z
          LEFT JOIN (
              /* ➊ Inner query */
              SELECT eq.contact_id contact_id, COUNT(*) sent
              FROM mailing_job j
              INNER JOIN mailing_event_queue eq ON eq.job_id = j.id
              WHERE j.end_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
              GROUP BY eq.contact_id
            ) engagement ON engagement.contact_id = z.contact_id
          ;
    ```
  - combine any or all of the above rewrites and test execution plans and results and add to the report the ones (queries and plans) that fail to produce correct results.

Testing in the latest subversions is recommended, as this may be a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll work my way through that. (the first 3 sql queries do as you suggest, except that #3 works (gives 15 not NULL) but this is as-stated in my question because you've included the id=1 clause ➍ - if I omit that and search the results for the row with id=1 the 2nd column is NULL not 15)

Comment: Your final query rewrite returns the corect, expected result, including without ➍, but - FYI and not necessarily relevant - it takes 214s vs 9s for my original.

Comment: 10.4.12 works, but my query is then as slow as yours :-)

Comment: @artfulrobot I assume the 214 sec are without the `c.id = 1` and returning a lot of rows. In any case, the rewrite was to identify where the issue is as it would probably produce different plan. Not to use it necessarily in production

Comment: So, I suggest you attach to your bug report (well done sending it!) at least one execution plan from a query that gets wrong result and also the table definitions (output of SHOW CREATE TABLE ...)

Answer (score 0):

Give this reformulation of C a try:

```
-- Query C 
SELECT  c.id contact_id, 
        ( SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM mailing_event_queue eq
            JOIN mailing_job AS j  ON eq.job_id = j.id
            WHERE  eq.contact_id = c.id 
              AND  j.end_date > NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
        ) AS sent
    FROM contact c
    WHERE  /* ➋ various conditions on table 'c' */
     ... (as before)
```

Comment: Thanks, this does work, but the real query is more complex and results in more than one field being extracted from the left join that you've moved into a select expression.